# Add button at the end of Recycleview in Horizontal linear layout (It must scroll horizontal including button

Tags: java, android

[image]
when I put button in linear layout after recycle view in Horizontal scroll ,It just shows 2 items of recycle view.Otherwise ,when I put it without horizontal scroll view then addititonal button didn;t display adter recycleview.

```
 <HorizontalScrollView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="260dp"
                android:scrollbars="none"
                android:weightSum="100">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">


                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/rv_upcomingPickup"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/iv_addPickup"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_5ssp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10ssp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_5ssp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_20ssp"
                        android:src="@drawable/addpickup" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: Share screenshot of what you want and what you get

Comment: @Piyush added screenshot

Comment: There are two ways to do. 1) If you want to add button as a sticky then using horizontal linear layout with weight you can do. 2) If you want to show add button after the end scroll then you need to add `VIEW_TYPE` to recyclerview.

Comment: I want to use first method .. I used above code but if only shows 2 items of recycle but it has 4-5 items

Comment: Then why are you using Horizontal ScrollView? You can simple use `RecyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager`.

Comment: Yes agreed if I directly put recycleview inside Linear layout then sticky button didn't get displayed

Comment: Yes. So go with my first solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `NestedScrollView` instead of `HorizontalScrollView` to scroll button.
 set  `recycleview.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);` to scroll smoothly.

Comment: yes ,I also tried but then my additional button didn't appear when i put in normal linear layout or nested scroll view with your provided guidance